# How to read from FireBase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have no clue how Can I read from Firestore.
I have tried different things and nothing seems to work well.
There is an error:

> I/flutter ( 8684): Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  void getMessages() async {
    print('ℹ️ getMessage function running!');
    final messages = await _firestore.collection('messages').get();
    for (var message in messages.documents) {
      print(' try to print message');
      print(message.data);
    }
  }
```

That function is triggered by pressing the button. It should download data from data base.

[image]

Comment: That is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), `data` is not a getter. It is a method so it must be called as such if you want the data in the `DocumentSnapshot`.

```dart
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  void getMessages() async {
    print('ℹ️ getMessage function running!');
    final messages = await _firestore.collection('messages').get();
    for (var message in messages.documents) {
      print(' try to print message');
      print(message.data());//Need .data() not .data
    }
  }
```

What you show in your question is not an error. It's just printing a function reference instead of the data returned by the function.

Comment: I am not really sure what do you mean.

Comment: @PawełBrzozowski What is unclear? You need to call the function.

Comment: Yes, I called it by pressing the button. But it prints I/flutter ( 8684): Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data': instead of message from firestore. Something is wrong with get() and messages.documents and I dont know what.

Comment: @PawełBrzozowski That's incorrect. Look closely at the code I post in my answer. Specifically the last print statement. There is a change I made that you're not doing. You are treating `data` as a getter, not a function as it is.